# Python: How can I go through all the values in this code?

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to get the info from an API.
I need to get info of this lines:

```
Lines = ["Piccadilly", "Victoria", "Bakerloo", "Central", "Circle" , "District", "Jubilee", "Metropolitan", "Northern"]
```

So I created this code:

```
url = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/'
tag = '?app_id=XXXXX&app_key=YYYYYYY'

for Line in Lines:
    r = rq.get(url + str(Line) + tag)
    time.sleep(2)
    info = json.loads(r.content)
info
```

The info I got is only for the last component of Lines and I would like to save information of every component in Lines in a dataframe.

This is what I got only for Northern

```
[{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
  'id': 'northern',
  'name': 'Northern',
  'modeName': 'tube',
  'disruptions': [],
  'created': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.35Z',
  'modified': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.35Z',
  'lineStatuses': [],
  'routeSections': [],
  'serviceTypes': [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
    'name': 'Regular',
    'uri': '/Line/Route?ids=Northern&serviceTypes=Regular'},
   {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
    'name': 'Night',
    'uri': '/Line/Route?ids=Northern&serviceTypes=Night'}],
  'crowding': {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowding, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities'}}]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the info to a list like this:

```
# create empty list
info = []

for Line in Lines:
    r = rq.get(url + str(Line) + tag)
    time.sleep(2)
    # append to list
    info.append(json.loads(r.content))
info
```

You can use this to insert the row into a dataframe, assuming your have already created a dataframe called `df`:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import json

    # put all columns in a list
    columns = ['id', 'name', 'modeName'] # incomplete list

    def insert(df, row):
            # get highest index
            insert_loc = df.index.max()
            # insert row
            if pd.isna(insert_loc):
                    df.loc[0] = row
            else:
                    df.loc[insert_loc + 1] = row

    for record in info:
            row = []
            for col in columns:
                    row.append(info[col])
            insert(df,row)
```

Comment: Thank you @J.D. could you tell me how can I get theses results in a dataframe?

Comment: I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning/overwriting `info`. Add/append to it instead using a data structure such as list or dictionary.

```
info={}
for Line in Lines:
    r = rq.get(url + str(Line) + tag)
    time.sleep(2)
    info[Line] = json.loads(r.content)
```

Comment: Thank you @Ricky Kim, could you tell me how can I get theses results in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
url = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/'
tag = '?app_id=XXXXX&app_key=YYYYYYY'

info={}
for Line in Lines:
    r = rq.get(url + str(Line) + tag)
    time.sleep(2)
    info[Line]=r.json()
print(info)
```

Comment: thanks and how can I save my results in a dataframe?

Comment: @Alexa the json you get back isn't exactly "dataframe ready". You would need to a bit of cleaning or moving things around before you could do that easily. And how you do that depends on exactly what info you are after.

Comment: I want to get this columns in my dataframe: 'id': 'northern',
  'name': 'Northern',
  'modeName': 'tube',
  'disruptions': [],
  'created': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.35Z',
  'modified': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.35Z',
  'lineStatuses': [],
  'routeSections': [],
  'serviceTypes': [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
    'name': 'Regular',
    'uri': '/Line/Route?ids=Northern&serviceTypes=Regular'} I tried with a for loop but it does not work, could you help me @SuperStew?

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding info at every iteration in the loop. One way would be to push every 
returned json in a list.

```
url = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/'
tag = '?app_id=XXXXX&app_key=YYYYYYY'
infos = []

for Line in Lines:
    r = rq.get(url + str(Line) + tag)
    time.sleep(2)
    infos.append(json.loads(r.content))

print(infos)
```

Comment: Thank you @Rambarun Komaljeet, could you tell me how can I get theses results in a dataframe?